# How to call a function in golang based on attribute change?

Tags: go

Sample code : https://play.golang.org/p/vl3xwMWf5G

In the above code, I am making sure that, we don't unnecessarily call the LocateBasket function. It is called only once during the GetBasketCall. But if there is any attribute change (For eg. The quantity was changed to 30) then I wanted to make sure that when user calls GetBasket it internally calls LocateBasket function too.

In my example I had only one function, but if there is multiple attributes which needs to be re-calculated (based on attribute change) when their corresponding Getter Functions are getting called, what is the best approach to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Write a setter method, and either immediately LocateBasket or flag it for GetBasket to do:

```
func (ball *Ball) SetQuantity(n int){
  ball.Quantity = n
  // ball.LocateBasket(ball)
  ball.dirty = true
}

func (ball *Ball) GetBasket() BasketType {
  if ball.dirty{
    ball.LocateBasket(ball)
    ball.dirty = false
    return ball.basket
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the problem with this approach is that it if there is multiple parameters , for eg. tomorrow if we have a new function "GetBasketColor()" which also needs to be changed based on the attribute - quantity then I have to implement the same logic in the other function too. And it becomes kind of redundant. And moreover if I set the ball.dirty=true in one Getfunction, the other GetFunctions might not be able to process based on changed quantity attribute.